# How can one reliably update a LOB column with data from another LOB column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I have tried: 
    `UPDATE "SCHEMA".TABLE SET LOB_COLUMN = (SELECT LOB_COLUMN FROM "SCHEMA".TABLE)`

I have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_LOB_DATA IS
    OLD_BLOB BLOB;
    NEW_BLOB BLOB;
    BLOB_LENGTH NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT LOB_COLUMN INTO OLD_BLOB FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE OLD;
    SELECT LOB_COLUMN INTO NEW_BLOB FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE NEW;
    SELECT dbms_lob.length(NEW_BLOB) INTO BLOB_LENGTH FROM DUAL;
    dbms_lob.TRIM(OLD_BLOB,1);
    dbms_lob.copy(OLD_BLOB,NEW_BLOB,BLOB_LENGTH);
    if (dbms_lob.compare(OLD_BLOB,NEW_BLOB) = 0) THEN
        commit;
    ELSE 
        rollback;
    END IF;
END;
```

and I've tried using cursors. Each method seems to work four times out of five, but every so often we'll encounter a field that just won't budge. the largest of these would be around fifty megs, but usually it's one of the smaller ones.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or anything? Try adding an `EXCEPTION` block to your PL/SQL to catch?

Comment: @Phil: adding an exception block won't make the error magically appear, quite the contrary! Don't catch unexpected errors, that's my advice.

Comment: @watt Is the error reproducible? You have to find a precise example, a specific LOB that you can't update for example. Then post the details here so that we can help you.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Well, yes. What I'm alluding to is that we can't help unless there's a specific error we can look at. Oracle isn't known to silently fail

Comment: A pure SQL update should work. Please post the error number you get.

Comment: @Phil I agree with you, however, an exception block here *will* hide the error :) so I pointed that it would be quite counter-productive!

Comment: @VincentMalgrat I was thinking about DBMS_OUTPUT or raise_application_error() to assist in debugging, and assumed the OP would realise that